# Bounding the ratio of two integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am trying to get a good upper bound on the following ratio:

$$I_n=\dfrac{\int_0^\infty xf(x)^n\phi(x)dx}{\int_0^\infty f(x)^n\phi(x)dx}$$where $\phi(x)$ is, in my case, the standard normal density, $e^{-x^2/2}$, and $f$ is kind of complicated looking but there exist constants $c$ and $C$ such that $ce^x\leq f(x)\leq Ce^x$ for $x$ large. Issue is, I am getting an exponential (in $n$) bound on $I_n$ whereas I want actually a $polylog(n)$ bound on $I_n$. If $f(x)=e^{ax}$ exactly, then I could have gotten such a bound. The inequalities are throwing me off.

Any help is appreciated. Is there a systematic way to handle such ratios of integrals?

Comment: If both integrals were $\int_0^n$, say, then $I_n \le n$ would be trivial (assuming $f(x)\ge0$ always). I recommend truncating the bottom integral to $\int_0^n$ (which only increases $I_n$) and then using the bounds on $f(x)$ to show that the contribution of $\int_n^\infty$ in the numerator is negligible.

Comment: With $f(x)=e^x$ the ratio is of order $n$, not polylog$(n)$.